# find Activation lock account type and name

Tags: android, device, account

I am trying to find account that have protection lock (we remotely lock the device like samsung account, google account, MI account)

I had find account of devices but it give me all account that available in device

````
        Account[] accounts = accountManager.getAccounts();



        for (Account TempAccount : accounts) {

            if (pattern.matcher(TempAccount.name).matches()) {
                Log.e("name", TempAccount.name + ".." + TempAccount.type);

            }
        }```

how i find out account that have protection lock enable
````